# Finding perfect matchings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, matching-theory

Given a connected graph $G$, do you have an idea how to calculate the amount of perfect matchings
this graph has (given at least one exists)? I dont worry about the calculation being efficient in any way, which I also can not expect at all.

I guess an idea would be to brute-force find all individual perfect matchings, but how to get even one for a graph we have almost no information about? I am also wondering if there maybe is an approximation algorithm for this problem, but i could not find any.

Comment: If your graph is bipartite, the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)#Perfect_matchings) yields the count of perfect matchings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding perfect matchings is a special case of [exact covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem. In general, we have a set $V$ and a collection $S$ of subsets (in your case, edges) and need to find a subcollection $S'$, $S'\subseteq S$, (in your case, a perfect matching) such that every element of $V$ is in exactly one subset from $S'$. All solutions can be found with Knuth's Algorithm X. To solve exact covering, I usually use [SAGE exact cover solver](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/dlx.html) or the [libexact](http://pottonen.kapsi.fi/libexact.html) library for C/C++ (libexact can also solve multiple covering).

Answer (score 2):

If your graph is [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#:%7E:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20a%20planar,no%20edges%20cross%20each%20other.) you can implement the [FKT Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm) which runs in polynomial time. Notice that Knuth's algorithm X is non deterministic and may take exponential time.